# Pushwoosh Notification Not Opening URL Specified

Tags: safari, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I'm setting a custom url in the "additional data" tab but for some reason the push notification is opening up the URL I entered for the URL template. How do I set a custom URL for each push notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pushwoosh Safari guide](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/safari/safari-website-notifications/) says:

> URL Template: The URL to go to when the notification is clicked. Use %@ as a placeholder for arguments you fill in when delivering your notification. This URL must use the http or https scheme; otherwise, it is invalid.

For instance, if you set the URL Template in app settings as http://example.org/%@/%@, in the Safari tab of the control panel you can specify the following placeholders:

1. pageid
2. 12345

so the push will open up the http://example.org/pageid/12345 URL.

The Additional Data tab in the Pushwoosh Control Panel is intended for mobile platforms only.